# Crew Dragon: Could launch escape thrust determine payload capacity?

Tags: falcon-9, payload, dragon, launch-escape

The superdracos in Dragon's launch escape system each produce $\color{black}{\texttt{71.2 kN}}$ (16,000 lbf) of thrust. There are eight superdracos, giving a combined thrust of $\color{black}{\texttt{570 kN}}$ (128,000 lbf).

If you assume a dry mass of $\color{black}{\texttt{9,570 kg}}$  (21,100 lbm) for Dragon, an empty mass of $\color{black}{\texttt{400 kg (880 lbm)}}$ for the payload *trunk*, a payload max of $\color{black}{\texttt{5,900 kg}}$ (13,000 lbm), and a combined MMH/NTO fuel capacity of $\color{black}{\texttt{2000 kg}}$, you get a total mass of $\color{black}{\texttt{17,870 kg}}$ (39,400 lbm).

Now consider the most demanding launch escape case: with Falcon at a peak acceleration of 3g and engines still running. At a minimum, you would need at least a hair over 3g in order to speed away, right?

Well, if you divide the superdracos' total thrust by the fully loaded Dragon's total mass, you get..

$$\frac{570,000 \texttt{ N}}{17,870 \texttt{ kg}} = 31.9 \frac{\texttt{m}}{\texttt{s}^2} = 3.25 \times \left( 9.8 \frac{\texttt{m}}{\texttt{s}^2} \right) = \textbf{3.25} \texttt{ g}$$

**And this has me wondering:**  Does launch escape impose an upper bound on the payload capacity that a Falcon + Crew Dragon assembly can carry to the ISS?

I'd always imagined that capacity was entirely determined by orbit specs and stage 1/2 fuel capacity, so that if your orbit was less demanding (launching straight eastward to low altitude, say) then you could launch with less fuel and stuff the Dragon trunk with whatever fuel mass you didn't load...

But now that doesn't at all seem the case... Because even if you launched with 10,000 kg less in stage 1/2 fuel, say, you still wouldn't be able to carry more than 5,900 ish kg while ensuring the crew can positively accelerate away from a failing rocket on launch escape.

Can someone confirm if this is true---that even if you could lift more load to orbit, you might be forced not to, in order to satisfy your launch escape requirements?

**EDIT**

3.25g is just a lower bound on the thrust acceleration you'd get from a Dragon + trunk + max payload + max fuel.

For an upper bound, you could assume a super light load approaching 0 kg. And in that extreme case, your superdracos would buy you ~50 m/s2, or just about 5 g's of acceleration.

And as your fuel load approaches 0 kg---at the end of your launch escape burn---your thrust acceleration would approach ~60 m/s2, or 6 g's.

So Dragon's launch escape acceleration would fall in the range [3.25, 6] g---though if you're maximizing load, you're likely to fall on the lower end of this range, and if your payload is over ~5900 kg, then you fall below your 3.25 g minimum and risk not having enough acceleration to positively speed away from a failing rocket in the worst-case scenario.

**EDIT 2**

I ignored the slant of the superdracos, which I believe is 15 deg to the vertical. This would make their combined thrust a bit less: $570 \texttt{ kN} * \texttt{cos}(15 \texttt{ deg}) = 550 \texttt{ kN}$.

This would give a thrust acceleration of 3.15 g for a fully loaded Dragon, if I stick to my mass numbers.

But [this article](http://www.collectspace.com/news/news-011920a-spacex-crew-dragon-in-flight-abort.html) shared by @BrendanLuke in the comments (thanks!) quotes the NASA administrator saying 3.5 g was the max thrust acceleration during launch escape tests (which I believe were done for the worst-case scenario with the rocket going ~ 3gs?).

This would mean a lighter Dragon + trunk + payload + fuel. The actual mass would have to be closer to (3.15 g) / (3.5 g) = 0.9 x my mass estimate, or ~ 16,070 kg instead of 17,870 kg---some 10% lighter. The lighter mass would probably come from a lighter Dragon capsule or from a lighter payload, since the trunk is already a super light 400 kg, and my fuel mass estimate is halfway between the lightest and highest numbers I've seen (1350 kg and 2,500 kg, if I remember correctly)?

And your peak acceleration with slanted thrusters and lighter mass would then be 5.5 g instead of 5 g with zero payload, approaching 7 g as fuel tanks empty out.

This would put launch escape thrust acceleration in the range [3.5, 7] g. But the main point remains: that accelerations over 3.5 g are possible only at payload mass under 5,900 kg (now maybe less as mentioned above), so even if the Falcon launcher could support more payload mass, you wouldn't be able to carry it without jeopardizing the astronauts' ability to escape in the worst-case scenario.

Comment: Well - we can just turn around your argument and say the performance of Falcon 9 limited the (useful) performance of the escape system. You can't construct a causality from the fact that the two systems match in performance.

Comment: Sure, the launch escape specs would come from your expected mission profiles, etc. But once you've selected your launch escape specs, they're *fixed* for *all* missions. There is no alternate set of launch escape thrusters you could use. It's just the 570 kN superdraco clusters. So once the launch escape system has been designed, it becomes a hard constraint on how much payload you can safely launch while retaining the ability to escape.

Comment: FYI, my post says nothing about what caused what. I start from the finalized specs of the launch escape system and of the Dragon/trunk vehicle, and figure out the worst-case acceleration you can get. And the numbers being what they are, that acceleration is just a hair over 3gs. So *whatever the cause* behind the numbers... all missions launching with a Crew Dragon are limited by the payload they can lift while still ensuring a worst-case escape if one should be needed. So you can't always carry as much as the rocket would allow you to.

Comment: It actually makes sense they would use just enough thrust to produce just over 3g acceleration. For one, ~3.25 g would be enough to positively accelerate from the rocket. No need for more. But more importantly, there are humans on board a Crew Dragon. And humans don't do well with high accelerations, which is why the rocket is limited to 3g (or some similar number). So you want more than 3g to positively escape, but not that much more that you risk unnecessary harm to the astronauts.

Comment: Although I've read that g-forces during launch escape can reach far more than 3gs for very short instants... but it doesn't seem those high g-forces would come from the launch escape engines alone... which the math says can produce just over 3g with a fully loaded Dragon + trunk + payload + fuel...

Comment: I think there's more nuance here, the engines are canted outwards at some angle limiting their effective 'vertical' thrust, but then [this article from CollectSPACE](http://www.collectspace.com/news/news-011920a-spacex-crew-dragon-in-flight-abort.html) quotes Jim Bridenstine saying peak g's of 3.5 during the inflight abort test of (a notedly stripped down) Dragon

Comment: Ah! You're right, Brendan. Only some of that max thrust goes into your net thrust acceleration. Thanks for the quote---I actually hadn't read anything on how fast the Dragon would accelerate during launch escape. 3.5g seems very reasonable. All my masses came from various places on the web, so they're probably off by some.

Comment: A 15 deg slant to the vertical would mean a total thrust of 570 kN x cos(15 deg), or 550 kN. With my mass numbers, this would mean 3.15 g of thrust acceleration. So (3.15 g)/(3.5 g) would mean 0.9x the total mass I assumed... or ~1800 kg less. Total Dragon + trunk + payload + fuel would then be closer to 16,100 kg than my initial 17,870 kg. The difference would likely come either from a lighter Dragon or from a lighter payload (since my fuel mass is in the reported range, and since the trunk is already a very light 400 kg).

Comment: Doesn't Dragon dump the trunk (and whatever payload is inside of it) in an abort scenario?

Comment: It does, but only after the superdracos shut down. The center of pressure of Dragon is above the center of mass, making it aerodynamically unstable, so that drag will cause it to flip until it is heat-shield forward (something important on reentry). The trunk is needed while the superdracos are firing as it forces the center of pressure to be behind the center of mass, allowing Dragon to stay nose forward until the superdracos shut down. You wouldn’t want Dragon to flip while the superdracos are firing and accidentally accelerate toward the rocket instead of away from it :D

Comment: Although it seems that with differential throttle control, you could get ample attitude control authority to keep Dragon nose forward until the superdracos shut down. After all, even the rocket itself isn’t always aerodynamically stable, especially early in launch when the tanks are full and the center of mass is very high(a different thread shows Saturn V was unstable early in launch), yet the rocket doesn’t flip because its attitude control system keeps it pointing the right way. Seems this would be possible for Dragon minus trunk too, but the finned trunk does help even if that’s the case.

Comment: Is it possible to fire both Draco and Super Draco at the same time?

Comment: I don't know... I've never seen both firing at the same time... Then again, I can't think of a reason why it can' t be done... But if the superdracos can handle the job by themselves---and they can---then why bring another 12 thrusters into the equation and risk extra failure modes? My guess is they could do it if they chose to but that they wouldn't choose to : D

Comment: @user39728 To move at more than the leisurely 0.25g (or less! The booster without the payload may get even better TWR than its normal 3g!) from what may any moment become a ball of fire and shrapnel? I think Soyuz with its ~12g escape system is a better approach, assuring definite survival in case of a catastrophic booster failure (while also assuring some serious, but non-permanent injuries)

Comment: I know! It seems little, right? But it's right on par with the acceleration of 3.5 g that NASA reported from launch escape tests. It helps that 3g is the fastest stage 1 would be going while carrying astronauts---though the 3g controller could be part of what fails in stage 1. I guess so long as they can reliably shut down stage 1 on launch escape, they have little to worry about, and it seems the odds of a stage-1 failure is far smaller than a launch escape failure, so...

Comment: But yeah, I think I'd prefer to escape at 12 g and know that any debris from stage 1 is well behind me. It just doesn't seem physically possible for Dragon to get anywhere near 12 g without a lot more thrust or a lot less mass... :/

Comment: "Does launch escape impose an upper bound on the payload capacity that a Falcon + Crew Dragon assembly can carry to the ISS?" no. The reverse. The maximum required mass that needed to be handled by the launch escape, determined the launch escape's ability.

Answer (score 0):

If your launch profile doesn't require you to hit 3G, you can increase the payload.  Such a profile would "waste" Delta V, but would remain within the escape envelope.

Further, if you trigger the escape does it not also cut the main Falcon engines?  So it should rapidly stop accelerating.

Comment: If the rocket is malfunctioning, you have no guarantee the engine controllers will be working right. They could well be failing too. So you have to assume the very worst possible case, because it could happen: that you're accelerating at a peak 3g, and that you cannot shut down the rocket engines before you fire the launch escape thrusters.

Comment: If you don't hit 3g, then you don't hit the upper bound imposed by launch escape (if in fact there is one). Doesn't mean the upper bound isn't there---it's just you never get close enough to it for it to matter. Just like a ceiling---it limits how high you can jump, and just because you can't jump high enough to hit it, doesn't mean it isn't there ;-)

Comment: @user39728 Interestingly, the [flight termination system (FTS), slide 13](https://www.gps.gov/cgsic/meetings/2019/valencia.pdf) reliability is greater than the Commercial Crew requirement for abort system reliability [Slide 29 "Commercial Crew Program: Key Driving Requirements Walkthrough". NASA. Archived from the original on March 28, 2012.](https://web.archive.org/web/20120328055242/http://commercialcrew.nasa.gov/document_file_get.cfm?docid=107) so potentially the likelihood of the abort system failing is greater than the likelihood of the FTS failing

Comment: @user39728 Another consequence of the FTS being more reliable than the (minimum required) abort system is that you potentially don't even have to consider (at least contractually) the possibility of aborting while still firing the first stage engines as it is outside of the odds you are required to achieve. This is (?perhaps) evidenced by the [in-flight abort](https://youtu.be/mu5Ydz34oVc) where they shutdown the engines while the abort was occurring.

Comment: Interesting! This is great to know. So OK, it seems you could get away with accelerations smaller than 3.5 g. If you assume you can always shut down the launcher engines (if they didn't completely fail), then even a small acceleration would be enough. Although it still would be smart to ensure you have enough thrust acceleration for that super unlikely but still possible worst case where you need >3g to speed away from the rocket. So if SpaceX wanted to fill the Dragon trunk to the brim when the Falcon launcher allows it, they can... and they have to decide if they *should* : D